# display memory usage per user

Tags: aix

How can memory usage in AIX7 by users, something like

```
prstat -a
```

in solaris?

I have tried using "svmon -U", however at this point it is largely unintelligible to me.

Comment: AIX is something of an uncommon beast. Voting to migrate to server fault (were much more of the population deals with such non-consumer systems ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use topas or nmon. You can find more commands in 
[Unix Rosetta Stone](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well I do not know what "prstat -a" returne, but try:

```
svmon -U -O unit=MB
```